# clang-format multiline variable assignments

Tags: c++, clang-format

For some project I'm trying to use a clang-format script to automatically format c++ files for me. When a variable assignment consists of more parts and it has to be split over multiple lines I want a newline after the variable name. Like this:

```
anytype result = veerrrryyyyloooonnnnggggvaaarrriiiaabbblleeenameeee + seccconnnddverrryyyloooonnnggvarriaabbleeenammeeee + orjustalotofvariablesinvolvedinoneassignment;
```

should become:

```
anytype result = 
    veerrrryyyyloooonnnnggggvaaarrriiiaabbblleeenameeee +
    seccconnnddverrryyyloooonnnggvarriaabbleeenammeeee +
    orjustalotofvariablesinvolvedinoneassignment;
```

I've been browsing through the clang-format style options and I couldn't find anything suitable for my case. I get this as an output of the format script:

```
    anytype result = veerrrryyyyloooonnnnggggvaaarrriiiaabbblleeenameeee +
             seccconnnddverrryyyloooonnnggvarriaabbleeenammeeee +
             orjustalotofvariablesinvolvedinoneassignment;
```

I looked through the clang-format style options and the option which is the closest to what I want (that I could found) is **AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings** . The example that comes with this option is what I want, but then I want it for all variable assignments.

> AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings (bool)

```
If true, always break before multiline string literals.

This flag is mean to make cases where there are multiple multiline strings in a file look more consistent. Thus, it will only take effect if wrapping the string at that point leads to it being indented ContinuationIndentWidth spaces from the start of the line.

true:                                  false:
aaaa =                         vs.     aaaa = "bbbb"
    "bbbb"                                    "cccc";
    "cccc";
```

But I want it not only to be for strings, but also for all other types of multiline variable declarations. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**
I made the problem concrete and I provide the files used. After discarding my wrapperscript and adding the style option AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings in a .clang-format file as suggested in a comment, the problem still exists. My clang-format version is 9.0.1 .
This is my clang-format file:
.clang-format

```
 BasedOnStyle: Google
 IndentWidth: 4
 AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: AllDefinitions
 AccessModifierOffset: -4
 AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
 ColumnLimit: 78
 AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
```

Input: main.c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string stringname1 = "something that could be input from somehwere";
    std::string stringname2 = "another string we have from somewhere";
    std::string looooongstringname = "very loooooooonggggggg long striiiiiiiiiingggggggggg" + stringname1 + "more thingss and more " + stringname2 + :"strings";

    return 0;
}
```

I used the command: $clang-format main.c > formattedmain.c and this is the outputted formattedmain.c file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string stringname1 = "something that could be input from somehwere";
    std::string stringname2 = "another string we have from somewhere";
    std::string looooongstringname = "raaaannndddoooommm teexxtt hheeeerree" +
                                 stringname1 + "more thingss and more " +
                                 stringname2 + : "strings";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings` is not only for string variables. It's for all source code strings. Did you *try* it? In what way does it not do what you want?

Comment: Yes I tried it. As can be seen in the last line of my question. The command there has "AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings : true" in the list of arguments, but it doesn't give me this outcome. Are you suggesting this option should do exactly what I want, but there is something wrong with the script, or the way it is called? Please could you check if there's anything wrong with the way I call the script?

Comment: Btw; I'd suggest creating a `.clang-format` file in the root of the source code repository rather than having to use a wrapper script and a huge command line. Then just use clang-format directly (or through your IDE/editor).

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that the option is exactly what you want. You may want to check that your clang-format version supports it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I made the problem smaller and created a new main.c and a new .clang-format file just to try this option. I editted the question. It's still not giving the result I want. Thank you for helping me look into this problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The documentation at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html seems to disagree with your interpretation of `AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings`. And my experimentation with it seems to confirm the documentation.